# How do I split a string with begin and end separators in JavaScript?

Tags: node.js, sockets, stream, pipe

I have a tcp socket with begin of package `"<<"` and end of package `">>"`, so my data is `"<< data >>"`.

```
let stream = socket.pipe(split('>>'));
stream.on('data', (data) => { /*do something with data*/ };
```

I am using this for cuting the end of package, so if i get:

```
<<data>><<data>><<data>>
```

My output is:

```
['<<data','<<data','<<data']
```

But some times my socket receive:

```
<<da<<data>>
```

And i cant respond the last data message, i wanna cut with begin `"<<"` and end `">>"`, and get data between.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp for that.

```js
const strP = "<<data<<<<data>>";
let tempResult;
const regExp = RegExp('<<(\\w+)(>>|<<)', 'g');
while ((tempResult = regExp.exec(strP)) !== null) {
    console.log(`Package data: ${tempResult[1]}`);
}
```